# Interview Question -- confused about the answer

Tags: number-theory, factorial

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers then how many possible solutions exist to the equation $a! = 5b! + 27c!$

A. No Solution
B. $1$ Solution
C. $2$
D. $3$
E. Infinite Solution

Comment: B doesn't appear in the equation?

Comment: I added B in the edit. Forgot lol

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try on your own and share your workings to get help.

Comment: I am new to these type of questions. But this is a linear equation, so I answered B. Is that correct?

Comment: Is it $(5B)! + (27C!)$ or $5B! + 27C!$?

Comment: Here the main thing is that is the sum of factorial numbers again a factorial!

Comment: I think answer is no solution!!!

Comment: it is 5B! + 27C!

Comment: Yes, according to what I read online about these type of equations, infinite seems plausible

Comment: @ironX A need to be a factorial number!but 5! + 27! Not a factorial number!

Comment: If $A! = 5B! + 27C!$ then $\frac {A!}{\min(B,C)!} = \frac {5B!}{\min(B,C)} + \frac {27C!}{\min (B,C)}$ is either equal to $5 + 27\frac {C!}{B!}$ or equal to $27 + 5\frac {B!}{C!}$.  Can you see why those are impossible?

Comment: "But this is a linear equation"  it most certainly is *not* a linear equation.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution is $32!=5.31!+27.31!$.

Otherwise if $b\ne c$, then either

(i) $b<c<a$, so $$a(a-1)\cdots(b+1)=5+27c(c-1)\cdots(b+1)$$ In this case $b+1=5$ since it is a common factor. There can be no other common factors, so $c=b+1=5$. But $a!=5.4!+27.5!$ has no solutions.

(ii) $c<b<a$, so $$a(a-1)\cdots(c+1)=5b\cdots(c+1)+27$$. In this case $c+1$, $c+2$,$\ldots$, must divide $27$. Since consecutive numbers cannot be multiples of $3$, $b=c+1=3,9,27$. But $a!=5.3!+27.2!=14.3!$, $a!=5.9!+27.8!=8.9!$, and $a!=5.27!+27.26!= 6.27!$ have no solutions.